# 3D Gaussian Process with different kernels per dimension

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pymc3

I am trying to implement a 3D Gaussian Process in Python.  The output of the function depends on two axes, call them x and y, that have different mean functions and different kernel functions.  In practice, I would just take:

K(x, x') * K(y, y')

But I do not know how or if I can implement that in sklearn.  I have tried reviewing the docs but I haven't seen how this could be handled; all combinations of kernel functions I have seen are of the form k1(x, x')*k2(x,x').

Is this solveable in sklearn?  Or GPy?  Or Pymc3? Or....

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For GPs, definitely check out [GPyTorch](https://gpytorch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Andrew Gordon Wilson et al. consistently push the state-of-the-art forward and have great documentation. [The KISS-GP method](https://gpytorch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/02_Scalable_Exact_GPs/KISSGP_Regression.html#KISS-GP-for-2D-4D-Data) specifically gives examples for higher-order outputs. (Note: I had AGW as a professor, so perhaps I'm biased.)

Comment: Thank you for adding that.  I've tried reviewing that documentation, but I'm not sure if this addresses the problem.  That said, I may be misunderstanding things so if there is a specific section that addresses this, I'd love to see.  :)  Thank you, regardless.

Comment: Oh, sorry - I think I may have initially misread your question. Instead it sounds that you're saying the two outputs are completely independent. In that case, couldn't one just learn two separate models, one for x and one for y?

Comment: I actually have just had that same realization myself! :)  Sorry to trouble everyone on this! :)

EDIT: I want to close this out, but want to give you credit.   I'm new to stackoverflow to not sure how this works, so let me know.

Comment: I added that as an answer, which you can accept. Feel free to edit the answer if you think more needs to be said, or you have a better way of phrasing it.

Comment: Nope I think that was perfect and succinct! :D  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two outputs, x, y, are truly independent, which the factorization

```
K(x_i, x_j) * K(y_i, y_j)
```

implies, then one could fit two separate models, i.e., one for each of them.